# Mqtt-client does not receive repeating message or payload when using qos2

Tags: java, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a problem with my client , I dont know where to look or pinpoint the problem but as far as I know im using qos 2 and my broker is mosquitto. Does anyone have any problem with messages that are not received but delivered?

My process is like these

1. ClientServer(acts as a bridge to the database) subscribed to "topic1"
2. Client publishes a payload to "topic1"
3. Something went wrong then ClientServer then send back to Client that it has not been saved.
4. Client receives the message and send the message with correct payload again.
5. ClientServer doesn't receive anymore (Mostly 2 - multiple times publish)

**Then i use another client to send some mqtt-client statistics to send a payload message to the ClientServer and in the ClientServer publish tokens most ImqttDeliveryToken data is pending. I dont know why is it because of QOS 2?**

So is there a problem with my current pseudo-code when using qos 2 with Client(having the same unique client-id) and ClientServer(having the same unique-client-id)?

*PS: What i meant about same unique client-id is that since runtime my clients dont use generated client-id to allow qos 2 to work.*

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here, but from your last sentence, every client must have their own unique client-id as the broker will only allow 1 connection per client-id

Comment: @hardillb ok thanks for pointing it out, I forgot the last process. Im really having a bad day after I figured the problem is in mqtt because its hard to debug if its not in your code.

Comment: @hardillb i misinterpret what i said sorry about that. I hope you take a look at the question again.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found my answer.

Seems like in order to get over from this problem is to enter higher number of

> `max_inflight_messages`
>
> (in mosquitto.conf )

to N number of messages that makes the ClientServer accommodate, it was its default was 10 that i think thats why 100+ records sent asynchonously will be pending or i don't know what happened but it stopped processing incoming messages.

As for my testing I set it temporarily to 1000.

Hope some people might enlighten me for additional information about this inflight messages?